# Saving encrypted file using python django

Tags: python, django

How can we save an encrypted file using python django..
In models field i used FileField to save encrypted file..  but it is not correct.. instead of file field which field can i use.. and How can we save an encrypted file using python django?

Comment: Is the file encrypted before you upload it?

Comment: What do you mean by *"it is not correct"*? Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [**full text** of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text. The code should be a [mre].